# JQuery/JS onclick change class of element inside link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of drop downs using bootstrap and I want to code in a simple function to change the class of my span element inside the link that is clicked.

To clarify...  Here's an example of the `HTML` I have:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-panel" aria-expanded="false"
    onclick="toggleIcon()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight"></span>
    Drop Down Title
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse-panel">
   <!-- content -->
</div>
```

I am looking for a function (using `JS` or `JQuery`) which can toggle the second span class to change between `glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom` and `glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top`.

Bear in mind, this function has to work for multiple drop-downs.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: right, so, you need a click event that toggles a class. there's an example on the learn jquery mini-site, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-helpers/ not really all that revolutionary.

Comment: How do I target the second span element?

Comment: That's basic dom traversal. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/ or, to be more specific, http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Comment: I linked to the tutorial. that should more than answer it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bad question that I can't delete because people have invested into answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .find('.glyphicon-triangle-bottom, .glyphicon-triangle-top')
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-top glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
});
```

Also remove `onclick="toggleIcon()"`

This should work for all anchor tags that have `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straightforward - better to use a $.click() function and get your classes right:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="toggle-icon" href="#collapse-panel" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight"></span>
Drop Down Title
<span class="icon-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse-panel">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

What I did up here was add the class of **toggle-icon** to the top link, and the class of **icon-toggle** to the span of the glyphicon...the JS is as follows:

```
// On Toggle-Icon Click
$('.toggle-icon').click(function(){
// Set Icon To toggle in function
var IconToToggle = $(this).find('.icon-toggle');
// If the icon is the bottom icon
if (IconToToggle.hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom')) {
// Change the icon to the top icon
IconToToggle.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-top');
// Otherwise
} else {
// Change the top icon to the bottom icon
IconToToggle.removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-top').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
}
})
```

Annotations added so you can read the code better. Hope this helps!

https://jsfiddle.net/khxehd05/

Comment: toggleClass will take care of all that if/else/hasClass work.

Comment: Pretty much could be shortened to:  `$(this).find('.icon-toggle').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom glyphicon-triangle-top');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#checkcls').click(function(){
  
  if($('#tglcls').hasClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom')){
    $('#tglcls').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-top');
    //to check class
    alert($("#tglcls").attr('class'));
  }
  else{
      $('#tglcls').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-top');
    //to check class
    alert($("#tglcls").attr('class'));
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-panel" aria-expanded="false" id='checkcls'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight"></span>
    Drop Down Title
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" id='tglcls'></span>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse-panel">
   <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this of course only works for one element, the OP needs it to work for  multiple...

Comment: what do u mean by multiple. Brother u have to assign the class names manually.

Comment: *"Bear in mind, this function has to work for multiple drop-downs."* by using an ID and not making use of `this` or `event.target`, this can only ever work with a single dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

So far answers here I would consider just mildly-ok (in my humble opinion).  Take a moment and read:

[Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

I would change a few things to make it look really readable and maintainable:

Html:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-panel" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight"></span>
  Drop Down Title
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom hide-on-expanded"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top hide-on-collapsed"></span>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse-panel">
 <!-- content -->
</div>
```

css:

```
[data-toggle="collapse"][aria-expanded="false"] .hide-on-collapsed{
  display: none;
}

[data-toggle="collapse"][aria-expanded="true"] .hide-on-expanded{
  display: none;
}
```

[Working JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xkr1jvco/)

1. I highly recommend you avoid at all costs using inline functions.  (`onclick="toggleIcon()"`)
2. Take advantage of CSS and what Bootstrap already does by simply writing html and css only!
3. Completely reusable, doesn't care what glyphs you use, doesn't require javascript, nothing is hard-coded in terms of events nor classes.

Comment: Additional, if you want to see it, I could add transforms to rotate the icon instead of it instantly pointing up/down...